# How to use the Parquet UUID Logical Type in a schema

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

Somewhat recently, the [parquet-format](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format) project added a UUID logical type. Specifically, this was added in [revision 2.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1125) of the parquet format. I'm interested in using the [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) library in Java to create some parquet files, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the UUID logical type in a parquet schema. A simple schema like this does not seem to work as I would hope:

```
message SimpleSchema {
  required int32 value1;
  required fixed_len_byte_array(16) value2 ( UUID );
}
```

I've tried many variations on this schema, and so far haven't managed to get it to parse with the **MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType** method. Is this a bug or limitation with the parquet-mr library? Or am I just formatting my schema incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parquet-mr library currently doesn't support the UUID logical type. There's an issue to track progress in implementing this feature [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1827).

Answer (score 1):

It is recently implemented:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1827
But isn't included in official `1.11.1` release yet. 
Please use `1.12.0-SNAPHOT` from github sources to leverage the latest functionality:
https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr